# Why is it that after showing an NSAlert nothing works?

Tags: swift, macos, nsalert

Why is it that after showing an `NSAlert` nothing works until I close the `NSAlert`?

I was trying to print a statement after the display of an `NSAlert` but `print` is not working.

Below I have attached my code:

```
let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()
alert.messageText = "Hello I am Message text"
alert.informativeText = "i am information"
alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK") // First Button
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel") // 2nd Button
alert.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.warning

alert.delegate = self
if alert.runModal() == .alertFirstButtonReturn {
    print("First Button clicked")
} else {
    print("Cancel button clicked")
}

print("after NSAlert >>>>>>> ")
```

[image]

Comment: You mean the `after NSAlert >>>>>>>` message is only printed after the alert is closed, but you want it to be printed as soon as the alert is shown?

Comment: @Sweeper  Yes it's not executing print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why.

Notice how `runModal` *returns* the result of the modal as a `NSModalResponse`. Code after the line `alert.runModal()` must be able to access the value that it returns, e.g.

```
let result = alert.runModal()
print(result)
```

If the code after `runModal` were run *as soon as the modal is displayed*, what would `result` be? The user has not clicked any buttons on the modal yet, so no one knows!

This is why when `runModal` is called, code execution kind of just pauses there, at that line, until the user chooses one of the options. `runModal` is *synchronous* and *blocking*.

Compare this with `alert.beginSheetModal`, which accepts a `completionHandler` closure, and the modal response is not returned, but passed to the `completionHandler`. This allows the code after the call to continue to run while the modal is presented, because the code after the call does not have access to the modal response. Only the code in the `completionHandler` does. `beginSheetModal` is *asynchronous*.

---

If you have something you want to print as soon as the alert is displayed, write it before the `runModal` call, and (optionally) wrap it in a `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter`/`DispatchQueue.async` call, so that your `print` is asynchronous.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
    print("Hello")
}
alert.runModal()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if alert.runModal()
```

This is executed in application-wide modal session

Here is from doc:

> Summary
>
> Runs the alert as an app-modal dialog and returns the constant that
>   identifies the button clicked. Declaration
>
> `open func runModal() -> NSApplication.ModalResponse`

Comment: My question is why.

Comment: using this also it's not executing print.